# How to remove simple response when displaying list card in actions on google for phone surface

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hi i'm having facing a problem that i have selected phone surface where returning both simple response and list card.But in display i'm getting both in simulator.How to remove the simple response when using or displaying list card.
This requirement is for both google home mini and assistant in phone.

> Here i need to clear that their is no request from user by clicking
>   list card.It is only meant for display purpose.

**whether my way of implementation is wrong or not don't know correct me if i am wrong.But is it possible to remove or any other way to get rid of the simple response?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that you **must** have at least one SimpleResponse, in addition to any other RichResponses you may send. This SimpleResponse can contain a blank space - but it must exist. (It should, however, probably include more than a blank space.)

Comment: Ok Thanks for advice @Prisoner

Comment: If a response is helpful, upvoting and/or accepting the answer is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Use following code to detect the Surface

  `const screenAvailable = conv.available.surfaces.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT');`
- If Surface present, only use UI based response.
- If Surface is not present, only use simple response.
- Test on a real mobile device and home as simulator shows extra information during simulation.